# pidgin & pidgin-data version conflict

Tags: debian, pidgin, debian-wheezy

My current os is debian wheezy.

try to install pidgin with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```

but version of `pidgin-data` doesn't match

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pidgin : Depends: pidgin-data (< 2.10.6-z) but 2.10.7-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I install pidgin?

Thanks in advance!

---

**edit**:
here is my source.list

```
~$ cat /etc/apt/source.list

#deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ squeeze main
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
```

here is install package information

```
~$ apt-cache policy pidgin pidgin-data

pidgin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.6-3 
  Version table:
     2.10.6-3 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
pidgin-data:
  Installed: 2.10.7-2
  Candidate: 2.10.7-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.10.7-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.10.6-3 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

other source packages in `source.list.d` were commented

Comment: Do you have a non-Debian package source in your apt sources file?

Comment: @EightBitTony `deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib` is my only package source.

Comment: And anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` ?

Comment: @Teifi You should use `apt-cache policy pidgin pidgin-data` to determine where the packages are installed from.

Comment: @Lekensteyn updated, `pidgin pidgin-data` were from the same source

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with **aptitude**. Its dependency handling may yield different results than **apt-get**.